# Executing a given Expression (without a delegate) where T is known only in runtime

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, predicate

I have class that receives Type and an Expression (without TDeligate).
I know the Expression is based on: `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` but I don't have the `T`. Instead I have the `Type`.
What I need is to execute the expression against a list and return the sub-list of results.
Something like `list.Where(Expression)`.
Here is the method:

```
public IEnumerable Query(Type type, Expression exp) {
    var list = GetListByType(type);
    return list.Where(exp); // << How do I make this happen?
}
```

**Edit #1**

I managed to turn my Expression to a LambdaExpression (as William suggested) like this:

> `var d = Expression.Lambda(exp).Compile();`

Now my problem is this: `d` above evaluates to `Func<Category, bool>` (where `Category` is the `T`).
Now, if I try to perform this: `return list.Where(d);` the compiler says:

> The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

The problem is is that I can't cast `d` to `Func<T, bool>` since I don't have the `T`.
As I mentioned at the beginning, I don't have the `T`, I do have `typeof(T)`.
Casting `d` to `Func<object, bool>` also didn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

How can I actually execute `d` against the `list`?

**Edit #2 (workaround / solution)**

I finally ended up generating some CodeDom to solve the problem.
If anybody finds a prettier solution, I'd really love to hear it.

Comment: could you provide more detail, this seems very abstract. from what you say i would suggest you would have to build the expression manually, but i'd like more information.

Comment: I believe you should create a Lambda expression from the `exp` parameter, using one of the `Expression.Lambda` overloads. Then compile it into a delegate using `LambdaExpression.Compile`, which you will pass to `Where`.

Comment: ermagana, some background: the method above is on a WCF server side. I use [Serialize.Linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) to serialize the exp on the client and pass it to the server as JSON.

Comment: William, I thought of going that path but I just couldn't get it to work (I'm fairly new to Expressions). Could you provide a sample I can play with?